# Can I load my Rasa NLU model stored in AWS S3 in Rasa server using a python script?

Tags: python-3.x, rasa, rasa-nlu, nlu, rasa-sdk

I have trained a Rasa NLU model for intent classification and entity extraction and uploaded it to a S3 bucket.

Now how do I load it to Rasa Server using a python script?

For example, using a CLI cmd:  `rasa run --model spacynlu.tar.gz --remote-storage aws` I can start the rasa server and load the model.

How do I achieve this using a python script?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but here is a solution for rasa 3.2.6.

I'm not sure about your exact use case - whether you want to launch the Rasa server from a Python script, or to load a model and use it for predictions. The solution below is for the later case. However, it should also help for the former use case - in general, you will need to set the environment variables as described below, and then use `os.system(server_cmd)` for launching the server, where `server_cmd` is the command you usually use for running the server, for example

```
server_cmd = "rasa run --model spacynlu.tar.gz --remote-storage aws"
```

just make sure that the value of `--model` is the full path in S3 to your model.

**Using `rasa` for parsing messages in a Python script, using a model stored on AWS S3**

Rasa is using `boto3` for accessing S3, so you need to have it installed. Then you need to set the environment variables used by `boto3` for accessing and authenticating. For example:

```
import os
os.environ["AWS_ENDPOINT_URL"] = "https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
os.environ["AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"] = "eu-west-1"
os.environ["BUCKET_NAME"] = "my-bucket"
```

You can, of course, set these variables in the shell, just make sure you export them.

For knowing the correct value for `AWS_ENDPOINT_URL` you can consult AWS documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html.

Now you can initialize an agent

```
import asyncio
from rasa.core.agent import Agent, load_agent

agent = asyncio.run(load_agent(
    model_path="my/path/to/models/mymodel.tar.gz",
    remote_storage="aws"
))
```

`load_agent` is a global function in `rasa.core.agent`. Note the `model_path` is the full path to the model, starting from the S3 bucket.
Also note the use of `asyncio.run` - this could probably be done in other ways, for example, for loading multiple agents/models simultaneously.

Once you obtain an agent instance, you can call, for example, the `parse_message` method on it

```
result = asyncio.run(agent.parse_message("Hello world!"))
```

(again, you can use `asyncio` in other ways.)

You can read the Rasa official documentation at https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/model-storage/#load-model-from-cloud, but it lacks some details.